# Java Unit Testing

Tags: java, unit-testing

I am trying to do some Unit Testing on my program and I need to test if an array is equal to another array so I need to write the code for Assert.assertArrayEquals(a2, a3), what would this code look like?

PS: I release this function is available in JUnit 4 but I don't have a new enough version for the provided function to work so I need to get code for one I got add to my tests.

Thanks

Comment: You asked this question yesterday at least twice.

Comment: You should not erase your question after you find the solution. Post it.

Answer (score 2):

The great thing about open source projects is that when you are curious how something works, you can just open up [the source code](http://github.com/KentBeck/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/Assert.java) and read it yourself.

Here is a hint on what conditions you would probably want to have met to consider two arrays "equal"

- Both arrays have the same length
- Both arrays have the same value at the same index

Comment: When you do a coverage test in Eclipse, how do you get a better percent?

Comment: @Brian, this seems like an unrelated question, but the answer would be: write more tests that cover the uncovered code.

Answer (score 2):

you can use Arrays.equals(a2, a3) method available in the Arrays class java.util pacakge

Answer (score 0):

to achieve above, u can use assertArrayEquals for org.junit.Assert, that will work for you, and if u want to implement in your own way, then you can write simple code to compare each element of the array in a simple for loop.